# Bash: Capture output of command run in background

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that will get the output of a command that runs in the background. Unfortunately I can't get it to work, the variable I assign the output to is empty - if I replace the assignment with an echo command everything works as expected though.

```
#!/bin/bash

function test {
    echo "$1"
}

echo $(test "echo") &
wait

a=$(test "assignment") &
wait

echo $a

echo done
```

This code produces the output:

```
echo

done
```

Changing the assignment to

```
a=`echo $(test "assignment") &`
```

works, but it seems like there should be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Bash has indeed a feature called *Process Substitution* to accomplish this.

```
$ echo <(yes)
/dev/fd/63
```

Here, the expression `<(yes)` is replaced with a pathname of a (pseudo device) file that is connected to the standard output of an asynchronous job `yes` (which prints the string `y` in an endless loop).

Now let's try to read from it:

```
$ cat /dev/fd/63
cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

The problem here is that the `yes` process terminated in the meantime because it received a SIGPIPE (it had no readers on stdout).

The solution is the following construct

```
$ exec 3< <(yes)  # Save stdout of the 'yes' job as (input) fd 3.
```

This opens the file as input fd 3 before the background job is started.

You can now read from the background job whenever you prefer. For a stupid example

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do read <&3 line; echo "$line"; done
y
y
y
```

Note that this has slightly different semantics than having the background job write to a drive backed file: the background job will be blocked when the buffer is full (you empty the buffer by reading from the fd). By contrast, writing to a drive-backed file is only blocking when the hard drive doesn't respond.

Process substitution is not a POSIX sh feature.

Here's a quick hack to give an asynchronous job drive backing (almost) without assigning a filename to it:

```
$ yes > backingfile &  # Start job in background writing to a new file. Do also look at `mktemp(3)` and the `sh` option `set -o noclobber`
$ exec 3< backingfile  # open the file for reading in the current shell, as fd 3
$ rm backingfile       # remove the file. It will disappear from the filesystem, but there is still a reader and a writer attached to it which both can use it.

$ for i in 1 2 3; do read <&3 line; echo "$line"; done
y
y
y
```

Linux also recently got added the O_TEMPFILE option, which makes such hacks possible without the file ever being visible at all. I don't know if bash already supports it.

**UPDATE**:

@rthur, if you want to capture the whole output from fd 3, then use

```
output=$(cat <&3)
```

But note that you can't capture binary data in general: It's only a defined operation if the output is text in the POSIX sense. The implementations I know simply filter out all NUL bytes. Furthermore POSIX specifies that all trailing newlines must be removed.

(Please note also that capturing the output will result in OOM if the writer never stops (`yes` never stops). But naturally that problem holds even for `read` if the line separator is never written additionally)

Comment: Thanks, that looks great!
Is there any way to get all the output from a reader without looping through every line?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that calling read line also acts as a call to "wait"?

Comment: Caution: if you want to use this in real life scripts, you'll need to create the file `backingfile` with `mktemp` and even use a `trap` as the combo `>`/`exec`/`rm` is not atomic!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Using it without the -d switch seemed to make it wait too - could it just be an impression caused by read line waiting for there to be at least one line in the buffer?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: This is all irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: No, `-d ''` is not equivalent to `wait`. It reads until it encounters the first NUL byte after at least one non-NUL byte has been read. Only `wait` is equivalent to `wait`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: No, there is no problem with atomicity. And no, a trap will not make anything more atomic.

Comment: @rthur: I've updated the answer to show how to get the output.

Comment: @rthur: `read` has nothing to do with `wait`. It's entirely process agnostic. It simply reads from an open fd into a shell variable.

Comment: @JoSo `trap` will not render anything atomic, it will just help you remove the ugly `backingfile` in case something goes wrong before reaching the `rm`. Regarding `wait` vs `read -d ''` you're right, I'll delete my comments.

Comment: Not entirely clear on the conclusion of this discussion.  Is there a missing call to `wait`?  Also, after `cat <&3` is `exec 3<&-` needed to close the file descriptor?

Answer (score 48):

One very robust way to deal with coprocesses in Bash is to use... the `coproc` builtin.

Suppose you have a script or function called `banana` you wish to run in background, capture all its output while doing some `stuff` and wait until it's done. I'll do the simulation with this:

```
banana() {
    for i in {1..4}; do
        echo "gorilla eats banana $i"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "gorilla says thank you for the delicious bananas"
}

stuff() {
    echo "I'm doing this stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm doing that stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm done doing my stuff."
}
```

You will then run `banana` with the `coproc` as so:

```
coproc bananafd { banana; }
```

this is like running `banana &` but with the following extras: it creates two file descriptors that are in the array `bananafd` (at index `0` for output and index `1` for input). You'll capture the output of `banana` with the `read` builtin:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' -u "${bananafd[0]}" banana_output
```

Try it:

```
#!/bin/bash

banana() {
    for i in {1..4}; do
        echo "gorilla eats banana $i"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "gorilla says thank you for the delicious bananas"
}

stuff() {
    echo "I'm doing this stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm doing that stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm done doing my stuff."
}

coproc bananafd { banana; }

stuff

IFS= read -r -d '' -u "${bananafd[0]}" banana_output

echo "$banana_output"
```

Caveat: you must be done with `stuff` before `banana` ends! if the gorilla is quicker than you:

```
#!/bin/bash

banana() {
    for i in {1..4}; do
        echo "gorilla eats banana $i"
    done
    echo "gorilla says thank you for the delicious bananas"
}

stuff() {
    echo "I'm doing this stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm doing that stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm done doing my stuff."
}

coproc bananafd { banana; }

stuff

IFS= read -r -d '' -u "${bananafd[0]}" banana_output

echo "$banana_output"
```

In this case, you'll obtain an error like this one:

```
./banana: line 22: read: : invalid file descriptor specification
```

You can check whether it's too late (i.e., whether you've taken too long doing your `stuff`) because after the `coproc` is done, bash removes the values in the array `bananafd`, and that's why we obtained the previous error.

```
#!/bin/bash

banana() {
    for i in {1..4}; do
        echo "gorilla eats banana $i"
    done
    echo "gorilla says thank you for the delicious bananas"
}

stuff() {
    echo "I'm doing this stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm doing that stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm done doing my stuff."
}

coproc bananafd { banana; }

stuff

if [[ -n ${bananafd[@]} ]]; then
    IFS= read -r -d '' -u "${bananafd[0]}" banana_output
    echo "$banana_output"
else
    echo "oh no, I took too long doing my stuff..."
fi
```

Finally, if you really don't want to miss any of gorilla's moves, even if you take too long for your `stuff`, you could copy `banana`'s file descriptor to another fd, `3` for example, do your stuff and then read from `3`:

```
#!/bin/bash

banana() {
    for i in {1..4}; do
        echo "gorilla eats banana $i"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "gorilla says thank you for the delicious bananas"
}

stuff() {
    echo "I'm doing this stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm doing that stuff"
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm done doing my stuff."
}

coproc bananafd { banana; }

# Copy file descriptor banana[0] to 3
exec 3>&${bananafd[0]}

stuff

IFS= read -d '' -u 3 output
echo "$output"
```

This will work very well! the last `read` will also play the role of `wait`, so that `output` will contain the complete output of `banana`.

That was great: no temp files to deal with (bash handles everything silently) and 100% pure bash!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. 
I ended up using Jo So's answer as it seemed like a simpler way of passing the output of a command to another fd - coproc does seem useful though.

Comment: @user2352030 JoSo's answer is not simpler at all! it's even more complicated as it forces you to create a file and remove it. And if you want to use his answer in a secure way, you'll need to use `mktemp`... and even probably with a `trap`! don't get fooled by what _seems_ simpler!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but from what I understood his portable sh shell method forces me to do that, but using the bash construct `exec 3< <(command)` does not.

Comment: @user2352030 another advantage of `coproc` is that you'll be able to determine whether the backgrounded process has finished by checking if the array `bananafd` is set.

Comment: @rthur yes you're right, as was talking about the last method.

Comment: coproc does seem to have it's uses, and it's probably a better solution for a more complex script - but in my case I'm only running two commands, and all that matters is that they start at the same time (or as close as I can get them to), and that I wait for both of them to complete before running them again with different input.

Comment: You can actually `wait` for the process to be finished by accessing `$NAME_PID` variable created when `coproc NAME ...` gets initiated.

Comment: Does `coproc` allow the `banana` output to be buffered up before being consumed? I was looking for a way to run something in the background, have its output saved in memory, and then consume its output after it was done (so I'm not synchronous stream piping).

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: in this case, I would use a temporary file.

Comment: Hmm... This looked like the best solution for a problem I had, but the fact that officially only one `coproc` may run at once limits it. It happened to work for four `coprocs` in my case (I was running four expensive commands to initialize four different bash variables in my `.bashrc`, and didn't like spending 2.5 seconds waiting for them to run sequentially when parallel execution could get it down to around 0.9 seconds), but dumped warnings about the three `coproc`s launched after the first one (because the first one hadn't finished yet).

Comment: While it's unlikely to happen: Note that there's a time between 'coproc bananafd { banana; }' and 'exec 3>&${bananafd[0]}'. If the gorilla is VERY quick, you lose its output!

Answer (score 15):

One way to capture background command's output is to redirect it's output in a file and capture output from file after background process has ended:

```
test "assignment" > /tmp/_out &
wait
a=$(</tmp/_out)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using files?

Comment: Yes, there is a (bash-only) way. See my answer.

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I also use file redirections. Like:

```sh
exec 3< <({ sleep 2; echo 12; })  # Launch as a job stdout -> fd3
cat <&3  # Lock read fd3
```

More real case
If I want the output of 4 parallel workers: toto, titi, tata and tutu.
I redirect each one to an different file descriptor (in `fd` variable).
Then reading these file descriptor will block until EOF <= pipe broken <= command completed

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Declare data to be forked
a_value=(toto titi tata tutu)
msg=""

# Spawn child sub-processes
for i in {0..3}; do
  ((fd=50+i))
  echo -e "1/ Launching command: $cmd with file descriptor: $fd!"
  eval "exec $fd< <({ sleep $((i)); echo ${a_value[$i]}; })"
  a_pid+=($!)  # Store pid
done

# Join child: wait them all and collect std-output
for i in {0..3}; do
  ((fd=50+i));
  echo -e "2/ Getting result of: $cmd with file descriptor: $fd!"
  msg+="$(cat <&$fd)\n"
  ((i_fd--))
done

# Print result
echo -e "===========================\nResult:"
echo -e "$msg"
```

Should output:

```
1/ Launching command:  with file descriptor: 50!
1/ Launching command:  with file descriptor: 51!
1/ Launching command:  with file descriptor: 52!
1/ Launching command:  with file descriptor: 53!
2/ Getting result of:  with file descriptor: 50!
2/ Getting result of:  with file descriptor: 51!
2/ Getting result of:  with file descriptor: 52!
2/ Getting result of:  with file descriptor: 53!
===========================
Result:
toto
titi
tata
tutu
```

**Note1**: coproc is supporting only one coprocess and not multiple

**Note2**: wait command is buggy for old bash version (4.2) and cannot retrieve the status of the jobs I launched. It works well in bash 5 but file redirection works for all versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just group the commands, when you run them in background and wait for both.

```
{ echo a & echo b & wait; } | nl
```

Output will be:

```
     1  a
     2  b
```

But notice that the output can be out of order, if the second task runs faster than the first.

```
{ { sleep 1; echo a; } & echo b & wait; } | nl
```

Reverse output:

```
     1  b
     2  a
```

If it is necessary to separate the output of both background jobs, it is necessary to buffer the output somewhere, typically in a file. Example:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

t0=$(date +%s)                               # Get start time

trap 'rm -f "$ta" "$tb"' EXIT                # Remove temp files on exit.

ta=$(mktemp)                                 # Create temp file for job a.
tb=$(mktemp)                                 # Create temp file for job b.

{ exec >$ta; echo a1; sleep 2; echo a2; } &  # Run job a.
{ exec >$tb; echo b1; sleep 3; echo b2; } &  # Run job b.

wait                                         # Wait for the jobs to finish.

cat "$ta"                                    # Print output of job a.
cat "$tb"                                    # Print output of job b.

t1=$(date +%s)                               # Get end time

echo "t1 - t0: $((t1-t0))"                   # Display execution time.
```

The overall runtime of the script is three seconds, although the combined sleeping time of both background jobs is five seconds. And the output of the background jobs is in order.

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
t1 - t0: 3
```

You can also use a memory buffer to store the output of your jobs. But this works only, if your buffer is big enough to store the whole output of your jobs.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

t0=$(date +%s)

trap 'rm -f /tmp/{a,b}' EXIT
mkfifo /tmp/{a,b}

buffer() { dd of="$1" status=none iflag=fullblock bs=1K; }

pids=()
{ echo a1; sleep 2; echo a2; } > >(buffer /tmp/a) &
pids+=($!)
{ echo b1; sleep 3; echo b2; } > >(buffer /tmp/b) &
pids+=($!)

# Wait only for the jobs but not for the buffering `dd`.
wait "${pids[@]}" 

# This will wait for `dd`.
cat /tmp/{a,b}

t1=$(date +%s)

echo "t1 - t0: $((t1-t0))"
```

The above will also work with `cat` instead of `dd`. But then you can not control the buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel you can probably use `parset`:

```
myfunc() {
  sleep 3
  echo "The input was"
  echo "$@"
}
export -f myfunc
parset a,b,c myfunc ::: myarg-a "myarg  b" myarg-c
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
echo "$c"
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html