# bash sequence: wait for output, then start next program

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, output, openvpn

In my case I have to run `openvpn` before ssh'ing into a server, and the `openvpn` command echos out "Initialization Sequence Completed".

So, I want my script to setup the `openvpn` and then ssh in.

My question is: How do you execute a command in bash in the background and await it to echo "completed" before running another program?

My current way of doing this is having 2 terminal panes open, one running:

```
sudo openvpn --config FILE
```

and in the other I run:

```
ssh SERVER
```

once the the first terminal pane has shown me the "Initialization Sequence Completed" text.

Comment: does openvpn actually terminate, or does it need to keep running? If it terminates then `sudo openvpn --config FILE && ssh SERVER` would work.

Comment: Hi @ChristianF, no openvpn does not terminate, it only terminates when i close the vpn connection.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems like you want to [run openvpn as a process in the background while processing its stdout in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20018118/27581).

```
exec 3< <(sudo openvpn --config FILE)
sed '/Initialization Sequence Completed$/q' <&3 ; cat <&3 &
# VPN initialization is now complete and running in the background
ssh SERVER
```

### Explanation

Let's break it into pieces:

1. `echo <(sudo openvpn --config FILE)` will print out something like `/dev/fd63`

   - the `<(..)` runs *openvpn* in the background, and...
   - attaches its stdout to a file descriptor, which is printed out by `echo`
2. `exec 3< /dev/fd63`

   - (where */dev/fd63* is the file descriptor printed from step 1)
   - this tells the shell to open the file descriptor (*/dev/fd63*) for reading, and...
   - make it available at the file descriptor `3`
3. `sed '/Initialization Sequence Completed$/q' <&3`

   - now we run *sed* in the foreground, but make it read from the file descriptor `3` we just opened
   - as soon as *sed* sees that the current line ends with "Initialization Sequence Completed", it quits (the */q* part)
4. `cat <&3 &`

   - *openvpn* will keep writing to file descriptor `3` and eventually block if nothing reads from it
   - to prevent that, we run *cat* in the background to read the rest of the output

The basic idea is to run `openvpn` in the background, but capture its output somewhere so that we can run a command in the foreground that will block until it reads the magic words, "Initialization Sequence Completed".  The above code tries to do it without creating messy temporary files, but a simpler way might be just to use a temporary file.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I haven't tried out bash's process substitution before so i'll be sure to read up on this now.

Comment: @MarcelM. I've updated the answer with my best attempt

Comment: Related to this: how would I stop the original background process (e.g. openvpn)?

Comment: When you want to exit status 1 when you encounter a different string `sed -e '/Completed/q' -e '/Failed/q1'`.

Comment: I want to use the code in a shell script `#!/bin/bash
    exec 3< <(sudo openvpn --config  /etc/openvpn/server.ovpn)
    sed '/Initialization Sequence Completed$/q' <&3 ; cat <&3 &
    ssh server`. executing that script throws me an error `line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<''. Have I misunderstood something obvious here?

Comment: This is great, thanks! I had trouble running this in a single line. I was missing the ";" right before "sed"

Answer (score 2):

Use `-m 1` together with `--line-buffered` in grep to terminate a grep after first match in a continuous stream. This should work:

```
sudo openvpn --config FILE | grep -m "Initialization Sequence Completed" --line-buffered && ssh SERVER
```

Comment: I just tried your command but it didn't work, it just paused which is what happens to the ssh command if it runs before the openvpn command is complete, so i think its being called before its complete. It does show the "Initialization Sequence Completed" line, but doesn't do anything after that.