# pause the bash script until "dmesg -w" outputs anything

Tags: bash

I came across this nice command `dmesg -w` which will output the device info when new device is inserted/removed.

Is there a way to use this command to pause the script untill user inserts any kind of USB  or SSD card? I was thinking of redirecting the output and using `read` somehow...

I normaly use the two command below to get device name from dmesg:

```
SSD_DMESG=$(dmesg | tail -n1 | grep -o 'sd[[:lower:]]')
SSD=/dev/$SSD_DMESG
```

Comment: What OS are you using that supports a -w flag to dmesg?

Comment: On Linux, at least, there are better ways to trigger events on device insertion and removal -- you can have udev or whichever equivalent your OS ships trigger only on device insertion and removal, rather than needing to constantly monitor.

Comment: @Nick Russo I am using ArchLinux. @Charles Duffy I have no `udev`, but I have `udevadm`.

Comment: @71GA, `udev` isn't a command, it's a daemon which can be configured. If you have udevadm, you have udev, and can craft an appropriate config file (typically under `/etc/udev/rules.d`) which will tell udev to start your script whenever a plug or unplug event happens. See http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script counts how many `sd[[:lower:]]` lines are currently in the dmesg queue.  It then waits for more lines to appear.  When they do, it prints them:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=$(dmesg | grep  'sd[[:lower:]]' | wc -l)
while [ "$n" -eq "$(dmesg | grep  'sd[[:lower:]]' | wc -l)" ]
do
        sleep 0.1s
done
sleep 0.1s
dmesg | grep  'sd[[:lower:]]' | tail -n+$n
```

`wc -l` is used to provide a line-count.  `tail -n+$n` is used to remove the prior existing lines.  The purpose of the last `sleep` is to allow time for the kernel to finish processing the device.

The above is verbose.  If you just want the `sd?` symbol and no other information, try:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=$(dmesg | grep -o  'sd[[:lower:]]' | wc -l)
while [ "$n" -eq "$(dmesg | grep -o  'sd[[:lower:]]' | wc -l)" ]
do
    sleep 0.1s
done
sleep 0.1s
dmesg | grep -o 'sd[[:lower:]]' | tail -n+$n | sort -u
```

Comment: Oh thank you this is a nice implementation of increments hehehe. :D

Answer (score 2):

`udevadm`'s `monitor` mode will provide a feed of `uevent`s as they are generated:

```
grep --line-buffered -o -m1 'sd[a-z] ' \
   <(stdbuf -i0 -o0 udevadm monitor --kernel --subsystem-match=block)
```

There's a few things here worth noting:

- `stdbuf` is used to [work around](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378) `udevadm`'s [output buffering behavior](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/17832).
- `--line-buffered` tells `grep` to output each line as it comes in instead of potentially holding it in a buffer.
- [BASH process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (The `<()`) is used to turn the output of `udevadm` in to a `/dev/fd/*` symlink that `grep` can open as a file and read from. If a pipeline was used instead (`udevadm | grep`), the `udevadm` process could end up hanging around even after the `grep` process has exited, which in turn would hold up the parent process.
- Remove the `-m` argument for a continuous stream.

Answer (score 1):

I've just recently tackled this same problem.  I'm trying to monitor `dmesg` so that I can discover USB MIDI devices as they are connected.

First, let's not use `dmesg -w`, since doing so will also display events that have occurred recently in the past.  Instead, let's `tail /var/log/messages` in refresh mode, specifying `0` lines to be displayed initially:

`tail -f -n 0 '/var/log/messages'`

Now that we know what command we want to monitor, how can we await a new `dmesg` entry that meets our criteria, and then terminate our polling?  Fortunately, `bash` redirection makes it easy to put a task into the background, and subsequently access its `STDOUT` and `STDIN`:

`exec 3< <( tail -f -n 0 '/var/log/messages' )`

Here, we've redirected the output of our `tail` operation into file descriptor `3`, which we can unset as follows once we've encountered our criteria:

`exec 3>&-`

Note that unsetting the file descriptor also terminates (via SIGPIPE) the command which was bound to it, so in this case, we don't have to worry about cleaning up the `tail` operation.

Now that we know how to bind and unbind our backgrounded command to a file descriptor, we can execute a `while` loop that will `read` and process each line of text provided via file descriptor `3`:

```
exec 3< <( tail -f -n 0 '/var/log/messages' )

local line

while IFS='' read line
do
  :
done <&3
```

The `read` command will patiently await new lines of text to appear on file descriptor `3`, and the while command will loop until the `read` command says that there are no more lines of text to read.  `read` would only do so if file descriptor `3` is closed, and since that descriptor is bound to `tail -f`, which never closes its output voluntarily, the `while` loop will not terminate, and we must thus manually break the loop.

Now we can add a statement that evaluates `$line` in some manner, and breaks the loop if some particular criteria matches.  Here, we can use the success status of `grep -o` to determine if we've found what we're looking for, and if so, do something appropriate, including breaking the loop and then closing file descriptor `3`:

```
exec 3< <( tail -f -n 0 '/var/log/messages' )

local line

while IFS='' read line
do
  echo "${line}" | grep -o 'sd[[:lower:]]' && {

    echo "YAY!  ${line} matched."
    break
  }
done <&3

exec 3>&-
```

If you want to implement a solution that doesn't use `bash` file redirection in this manner, please refer to several useful alternatives documented at [Bash: Capture output of command run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017805/bash-capture-output-of-command-run-in-background).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents.  Use `timeout`, `journalctl`, `stdbuf`, and `grep`; thusly:

```
if timeout $max_to stdbuf -oL -eL journalctl -b -f | grep -l  --line-buffered "."; then
    # grep found what you were looking for.
else
    # TIMEOUT
fi
```

Let's start with `grep`.  The -l option with cause grep to return as soon as a match is found.  `--line-buffered` eliminates the buffering problem with grep only. '.' will match anything.

`journalctl -b -f` tell journalctl to print messages starting from the boot time and continue to output messages until terminated.  This means that you won't have to worry about a race condition where the message that you're looking for happened before your call to `dmesg`.

`stdbuf` will eliminate the buffering issues with journalctrl.

And now for the coup de gras, the `timeout` command will terminate everything if the command following it doesn't terminate before the given number of seconds; beautiful!