# set variable in subshell

Tags: bash, sh

I have a script like this that works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

INBOUND=$(echo '5')
OUTBOUND=$(echo '10')

TOTAL=$(($INBOUND+$OUTBOUND))

echo "IN:$INBOUND OUT:$OUTBOUND T:$TOTAL"
```

Output: `IN:5 OUT:10 T:15`

Now suppose instead of `echo 5` and `echo 10` I have two commands that takes 10 seconds each to run.

I don't want my script to take 10+10 seconds to run and so I'm trying to use two sub-processes for each variable.

I thought whis would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

INBOUND=$(echo '5') &
OUTBOUND=$(echo '10')
wait
TOTAL=$(($INBOUND+$OUTBOUND))

echo "IN:$INBOUND OUT:$OUTBOUND T:$TOTAL"
```

But the first variable doesn't get a value and the output is: `IN: OUT:10 T:10`

How can I set each var in a separate process, so the script runs in 10 seconds instead of 10+10 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017805/bash-capture-output-of-command-run-in-background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use (temporary) files.

```
inbound_result=$(mktemp)
outbound_result=$(mktemp)
echo '5' > "$inbound_result" &
echo '10' > "$outbound_result" &
wait
read inbound < "$inbound_result"
read outbound < "$outbound_result"
total=$((inbound + outbound))

echo "IN: $inbound OUT:$outbound T:$total"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!