# Two way communication with process

Tags: linux, bash

I have given some compiled program. I want to communicate with it from my bash script by program stdin and stdout. I need two way communication. Program cannot be killed between exchange of information. How I can do that?
Simple example:

Let that program be compiled partial summation (C++) and script results will be squares of that sums. Program:

```cpp
int main() {
    int num, sum = 0;
    while(true) {
        std::cin >> num;
        sum += num;
        std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My script should looks like that:

```sh
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    echo "$i" > program
    read program to line;
    echo $((line * line))
done
```

If in program I have `for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)`, then I can do something like that:

```sh
exec 4< <(./program); # Just read from program

for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    read <&4 line;
    echo "sh: $((line * line))";
done
```

For more look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017805/bash-capture-output-of-command-run-in-background). From the other hand, if in program I have `std::cout << sum * sum;`, then solution could be:

```sh
exec &3> >(./program); # Write to program

for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    echo "$i" > &3
done
```

My problem is two way communication with other process / program. I don't have to use exec. I cannot install third party software. Bash-only solution, without files, will be nice.

If I run other process, it will be nice to know pid to kill that at the end of script.

I think about communication with two or maybe three processes in the future. Output of firs program may dependents on output of second program and also in second side. Like communicator of processes.

However, I cannot recompile programs and change something. I have only stdin and stdout communication in programs.

Comment: I guess your C++ program should support POSIX pipes. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2789967/524743

Comment: Redirection (using `>` or `<`) does not work like that. What you want is definitely *pipes*.

Comment: @Samuel thank you for your answer. If I can edit Cpp program, then I know how to communicate between two processes. But it's impossible to recompile program and change it. I have only stdin and stdout communication in program.

Comment: If you could install additional software you could use [expect|http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect]. This way you could script an interactive process.

Comment: @cb0 Program Expect (5.45) is installed  on the target machine. I will read about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have bash which is newer than 4.0, you can use [coproc](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc).

However, don't forget that the input/output of the command you want to communicate might be buffered.

In that case you should wrap the command with something like `stdbuf -i0 -o0`

Reference: [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered)

Here's an example

```
#!/bin/bash
coproc mycoproc {
  ./a.out # your C++ code
}
# input to "std::cin >> num;"
echo "1" >&${mycoproc[1]}
# get output from "std::cout << sum << std::endl;"
# "-t 3" means that it waits for 3 seconds
read -t 3 -u ${mycoproc[0]} var 
# print it
echo $var

echo "2" >&${mycoproc[1]}
read -t 3 -u ${mycoproc[0]} var
echo $var

echo "3" >&${mycoproc[1]}
read -t 3 -u ${mycoproc[0]} var
echo $var

# you can get PID
kill $mycoproc_PID
```

output will be

```
1
3
6
```

If your bash is older than 4.0, using `mkfifo` can do the same thing like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo f1 f2
exec 4<> f1
exec 5<> f2
./a.out < f1 > f2 &

echo "1" >&4
read -t 3 -u 5 var
echo $var

rm f1 f2
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your C++ program reads from standard output, and prints to standard output, it's easy to put it inside a simple chain of pipes:

```
command_that_writes_output | your_cpp_program | command_that_handle_output
```

---

In your specific case you probably need to modify the program to only handle one single input and writing one single output, and remove the loop. Because then you can do it very simple, like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    result=`echo $i | ./program`
    echo $((result * result))
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my unsimplified problem second number given to program dependents on earlier output of program, or even on other program output, so I cannot do it like that.

Comment: @Tacet Then continue the chain of pipes? That's how chaining output from one program as input to another is done in the POSIX world.