# Capturing the output of a detached command makes the execution sequential

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command in parallel by detaching it:

> **sleep 2s &**

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
    sleep 2s &
    pids[${i}]=$!
done

for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
    wait $pid
done
```

Which will spawn 3x the command 'sleep 2s' and wait for the commands to be finished

This is executed as expected (2 seconds):

> pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts $ time ./test.sh
>
> real  0m**2.029s**
>   user  0m0.022s
>   sys   0m0.052s

When I try to capture the output of the process, the execution changes from parallel to sequential. The execution time is now 6 seconds (3x 2 seconds)

> output[${i}]=$(**sleep 2s &**)

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
    output[${i}]=$(sleep 2s &)
    pids[${i}]=$!
done

for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
    wait $pid
done
```

> pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts $ time ./test.sh
>
> real  0m**6.030s**
>   user  0m0.006s
>   sys   0m0.015s

Any ideas on how to capture the output whilst running the commands in parallel?
Thanks!

Comment: What output are you trying to capture out of `sleep 2`, do you have some other command to run?

Comment: How could the variable possibly obtain a value before the process whose output you are capturing has finished?

Comment: @Inian I used sleep as an example, the actual command is to program a PIC chip via pickle (http://hg.kewl.org/pub/pickle), but I think it is irrelevant to my question ;)

Comment: @JonathanV: Using command-substitution(`$(..)`) won't work for your case. So your problem is try to capture output of a command running in background right?

Comment: @Inian, yes exactly. writing to a file would be an option, but i prefer an option that does not leave traces after the execution (like a variable)

Comment: @JonathanV: Would answers in this question help you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/20017805/5291015. If so I'm closing this as a duplicate